# how to check whether the given field is alphanumeric or not in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, playframework-json

i have to check either the password field is alphanumeric or not and if not it will throw custom Validation error i am using play-framework but  getting compile time error

```
value checkAlphanumeric is not a member of 
     play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
    - value checkAlphanumeric is not a member of 
     play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
```

i am unable to achive my desired outcome i am doing it wrong that's why i need here is the code

```
case class userUserSignUpValidation(firstName: String,
                                      lastName: String,
                                      email: String,
                                      password: String) extends Serializable

object UserSignUpValidation {
  val allNumbers = """\d*""".r
  val allLetters = """[A-Za-z]*""".r
  var validationErrorMsg=""
  implicit val readDirectUser: Reads[DirectUserSignUpValidation] = (
    (JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "lastName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](8)checkAlphanumeric))(UserSignUpValidation.apply _)
    def checkAlphanumeric(password:String)={
        val allNumbers = """\d*""".r
        val allLetters = """[A-Za-z]*""".r

        val errors = password match {
          case allNumbers() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))
          case allLetters() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))
          case _ => Nil
        }
     }
```

i am getting the error on this line

```
(JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](8)checkAlphanumeric))(UserSignUpValidation.apply _)
```

what is the right way to implement an above scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot use your `checkAlphanumeric` method that way. What you probably want is a filter on the `Reads`, so I would suggest doing something as follow (I changed the implementation for the check, using pre-existing methods):

```
implicit val readDirectUser: Reads[DirectUserSignUpValidation] = (
  (JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "lastName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](8).
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))(_.forall(_.isDigit)).
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))(_.forall(_.isLetter))
    )) (UserSignUpValidation.apply _)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I wonder why don't you run validations inside case class?

```
case class userUserSignUpValidation(firstName: String,
                                      lastName: String,
                                      email: String,
                                      password: String) {

   assert(!password.matches("""[A-Za-z]*""") && !password.matches("""\d*"""), "Invalid password")
   // have other field validations here
}
```

And in you UserSignUpValidation use a implicit formatter like this:

```
object UserSignUpValidation {
   implicit val userFormatter = JSON.format[userUserSignUpValidation]

    // de-serialization code here
}
```